# GetProperty in Generic class returns null

Tags: c#, generics

In a project I'm working has a class defined like this:

```
class DataImport<T> : DataBaseClass where T : IDataEntity, new()
{
}
```

The `IDataEntity` has fields like this:

```
string tableName { get; }
string Id { get; }
int TypeId { get;  }
```

In a class that implements this interface there is this:

```
string IDataEntity.Id { get { return myobject_id.ToString(); } }        
int IDataEntity.TypeId { get { return 10; } }
string IDataEntity.tableName { get { return "tblObjects"; } }
```

For example.

In the `DataImport` object I would like to do this:

```
string x = (T).tableName;
```

etc. But of course I can't do that.
I've tried declaring them as public but it's not allowed.

How would I access the `tableName`, `Id` and `TypeId` properties? I've looked at `typeof(T).GetProperties()` but they are `null`; in `GetFields()` also.

Comment: You need an _instance_ of `T` to call a non-static property.  Do you have one?

Comment: Yes, I am in the code. But I'm not passing the parameter (T) to the method. I just realized I think I need to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. You need an instance of `T` to access the *non-static* property `tableName`, in your example you call `(T).tableName` on the *type* instead of an *instance*.
2. Since your class implements the interface explicitly (`string IDataEntity.tableName`) you will need to cast the instance of `T` into an `IDataEntity` explicitly.

So your `DataImport` implementation should look like this:

```
class DataImport<T> : DataBaseClass where T : IDataEntity, new()
{
    public void WriteTableName(T arg)
    {
        string x = ((IDataEntity)arg).tableName;
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how I can use T as a modifier for arg. I can get the specific name of the class by this: int index = typeof(T).Name.IndexOf("EntityName"); and then parse that but I cannot get deeper into the object.

Comment: @Ron not sure what you mean by "modifier"... `T` is the type of `arg`. At runtime It's the type you use to instantiate a specific class of `DataImport<YourType>`.

Comment: @Ron maybe you should show what _exactly_ you want to do (but I'm offline now for some hours)

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what it is. class DataImport<T> : DataBaseClass where T : IDataEntity, new()
    {
       
        public override int Run(int Length)
        {
            int index = typeof(T).Name.IndexOf("Entity");
   //BUT I would like to get to what specific T this is
   //so I can examine more data elements
   //like typeof(T).GetProperty("tblName");
   
   but that returns null.  I feel I'm going in circles.

Comment: it seems a little misconception to make a generic class and then needing to know the specific type. anyway, `tableName` is an _instance property_ so you need at least to use the `GetProperty` overload that takes the instance as parameter. How should the _type_ know the value of a property of an _instance_? writing on phone so not able to update the answer now with more details and documentation links.

Comment: little flaw in last comment: you probably need `typeof (IDataEntity).GetProperty ()` to get the property info and then pass the instance to `GetValue` (if I remember the method name correctly)

Comment: All the GetProperties() or GetFields() return generic values or nulls. I'm trying typeof(XYZ)<T>.GetProperty() but again, null or generic properties depending on what XYZ is. I can get to the name but not beyond the name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112068/discussion-between-ron-and-rene-vogt).